# How to view List of Available WIFI Networks Programatically in Windows Phone8 App

Tags: .net, html, windows-phone-8, c#-5.0

I am Developing an application in which home page should display list of all available WiFi networks(open or secure). On clicking on any of the network in list it should connect to that WIFI.

How can it be possible in windows phone8?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get a list of available WiFi networks via any of the public APIs.

It will not be possible to build the app you describe on Windows Phone.
The ability to view available WiFi networks and choose the one to connect to is already included in the phone settings.

Comment: True.. Karthik You can mark it as answered. The requirement you mentioned is not implementable.